# Laravel - unsigned with nullable

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, migration

I am using Laravel 5.3, I want to define a field in table migration as **nullable** as well as **unsigned**. As both are index modifier, can I use them in concatenation ? Like:

```
$table->integer('some_field')->unsigned()->nullable();
```

Please also give some reference if there is to these kind of modifications in laravel documentation or somewhere.

Please note that I want to define field in `up()` function as unsigned as well as nullable. I dont want solutions with `down()` function like:

```
public function up()
    {
       Schema::create('ex', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->integer('some_field')->unsigned();
       });
    }
public function down()
    {
        DB::statement('ALTER TABLE ex MODIFY `some_field` integer NOT NULL;');
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: No I didn't and I can not at the moment as I can't create test env from some reason so I was hoping if anyone knows it for sure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can. Laravel allows a lot of method-chaining. Each of the column methods is defined to return the same `Blueprint` object, so you can easily call another method on it. This means you could even do:

```
Schema::create('ex', function (Blueprint $table) { 
  $table->integer('some_field')->unsigned()->default(10); 
});
```

And all would be well :)

For further information, see [the documentation on database migrations](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/migrations) (see the section on "Column Modifiers").

Comment: Its strange though. I knew that we can use **column types** and **column modifier** together but its good to know that **index modifier** can be concatenated too. Thanks for your answer. +1 and accepted!

Comment: what is `first()` doing in your chain?

Comment: Thanks @Adam. Good catch. I have no idea what I was thinking. 

Answer (score 13):

You can do

```
   Schema::create('ex', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->integer('some_field')->unsigned()->nullable();
   });
```

Answer (score 1):

Although this question has been answered. I also chose the accepted answer which confirms that using:

```
$table->integer('some_field')->unsigned()->nullable();
```

is right.

Although I am listing one more way to do same:

```
$table->integer('some_field')->unsigned();
$table->integer('some_field')->nullable()->change();
```

with reference : https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/migrations#modifying-columns

Comment: Correct. I think the `change` method though is for when you already have run your old migrations and you don't want to refresh them.

Comment: Indeed it is for that. Mostly used in `down()` function but still , it is an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

**In laravel 8.***

```
Schema::table('table_name', function (Blueprint $table) {
  $table->unsignedInteger('column_name')->nullable();
});
```